# keras lstm translation model wrong predictions when adding or deleting one word

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm new to keras seq2seq LSTM models. I have a working machine translation model and English-to-Arabic training data. I just trained the model using google colab tool and made some predictions. As you can see in the image, when I test the model on a text from the training data, it predicts well, but when I change ONE word, the prediction goes completely wrong!
I want my model to UNDERSTAND the full meaning of the text even when adding/deleting one word. How can I solve this problem?

[LSTM wrong predictions when adding/deleting one word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXzkp.png)

In the image, the first test of each section is the text from the training data, which predicts well. The second test is the same but with adding/deleting one word.

**UPDATE:** Whenever I add validation split, the val_loss is always increasing and the model isn't learning too much! What's going worng?

Comment: With more training data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the classical overtraining problem. Your model only learn to translate your training data by remembering each sample instead of understanding the concept behind it.

For this reason always split your training data in training data and validation data. The validation data must not be in the training data set! This way you can check if your model is actually learning something.

There are two main solution for this:

1. Like m33n said more training data (there is no data like more data)
2. Implement more regularization techniques like Dropout

Also the problem seems very ambigous. Translating sentences is not an easy task at all and copanies like google or deepl created very complex models trained with lots and lots of data occupied over years. Are you sure you have the necessary resources to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I updated the question. How to add dropout layer to functional model?

Comment: Like every other layer: Dropout(0.5)(previous_layer)

Comment: After what layer should I add it? Sorry for dumb questions I'm new to this :)

Comment: You have to try this out. Normally not too close to the input and output layer.